# pie chart in tikzpicture shows the colors' names

Tags: latex, pie-chart, tikz

I am trying to create a simple pie chart using tikzpicture in Latex. The problem is that the result shows the colors names also. How can I remove these texts?

Here is the script: I included the pgf-pie package.

```
 \documentclass[2019]{elsarticle}
 \usepackage{pgf-pie}

 \begin{document}


 %Pie chart
 \begin{figure}
 \scriptsize
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
 \pie [ color ={ gray!10 , gray!40}]{90/A, 10/B}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \centering
 \caption{Pie chart showing distribution of the papers on different mobile operating systems.}
 \label{fig:pieChart}
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code fragment works fine for me. Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I edited my question. I created a new .tex file and copied the exact code into it, but the result was the same. I guess the problem is related to document class type which is Elsevier.

Comment: Thanks for the complete code. Your code still works fine for me. Can you add `\listfiles` to your document and copy the resulting list of package versions from the .log file to your question?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the solution. It seems that the problem is related to the pgf-pie package. The solution is here: 
  [Problem generating pie chart with pgf-pie package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469477/problem-generating-pie-chart-with-pgf-pie-package)